# Change Entity Framework generated model classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently confusing myself or doing something wrong, could someone please help me to better understand this?

I am creating an application using ASP.Net MVC 5 and using Entity Framework, so what I have done I created the database tables and updated the Entity Framework from the database, so it creates a nice diagram for me and so, also it creates Model classes for me, which is great. However right at the top of the Model class I get the following comment: 
[image]

and I have some get and set methods that have been generated by the database, however for the following attributes I want to add [Required] at the top but it always get overwritten, any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Check this => http://alexwolfthoughts.com/adding-validation-metadata-to-entity-framework-generated-classes/

Comment: Thanks for the link, is there any other suggestion? This way I will end up with 3 classes, one that is auto-generated, other that is EmployeeMap and the last one EmployeeMeta. Having three classes for each of my model is overkilling

Comment: There wouldnt be 3 classes there would only be 2 classes. One for Employee and one for EmployeeMetadata. Partial classes are not a different class.

Comment: @Shoe According to the article I am suppose to create an EmployeeMap class that will have `[MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMeta))]` at the top and then create another one called EmployeeMeta that will have the MetaTags, so in my opinion I will be creating additional 2 classes and another one that will be auto-generated, unless I am missing something here

Comment: @Shoe Thanks makes sense now. I came across this article [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148486/Adding-Metadata-to-Entities-in-The-Data-Model), the other one is too bad

Answer (score 0):

I should have really looked at this first http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148486/Adding-Metadata-to-Entities-in-The-Data-Model

It suggests that I create another model class with metadata in it, which is okay, not massive overwork, so thats cool

Many thanks